# JavaScript: Submit and Prevent

Tags: javascript, forms

I try to trigger form submitting and prevent the submission at the same time. What I mean: When you select a file, JS will attempt to submit, but will also run a function (`onsubmit`) that prevents the action.

And that's my code (No jQuery, just trying to make it look like php):

```
var $form, $file, $files;

$form  = document.querySelector('form#form-1'),
$file  = $form.querySelector('input[type="file"]'),
$files = null;

$file.onchange = function($e){
    $files = $e.target.files;
    $form.submit();
};

$form.onsubmit = function($e){
    $e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Default Prevented');

    // Xhr will go here, if the browser will prevent
    // it from being submitted
};
```

I know that the problem might be because I'm confusing the browser and tells once to submit and then to prevent, but how can I make it work as expected? I'm planning to insert xhr within the `$form.onsubmit` function that should to the required job, but It won't, at least as long as the browser will submit the function without preventing it from being submitted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form onsubmit doesn't work with form .submit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568545/form-onsubmit-doesnt-work-with-form-submit)

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/25568709/2119863

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of invoking `onsubmit` handler manually, move AJAX call into separate function and call it from both handlers:

```
$file.onchange = function($e){
    $files = $e.target.files;
    sendForm($form)
};

$form.onsubmit = function($e) {
    $e.preventDefault();
    sendForm($form)
};

function sendForm(form) {
    // Xhr will go here, if the browser will prevent
    // it from being submitted
    console.log('send form with AJAX');
}
```

UPD. If you really-really want to trigger event you should do it with dispatchEvent method, as (thanks @NathanP. for pointing it out) just calling `$form.submit()` is not going to trigger it:

```
$file.onchange = function($e){
    $files = $e.target.files;
    var event = new Event('submit', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true 
    });
    $form.dispatchEvent(event);
  };

  $form.onsubmit = function() {
      console.log('send form with AJAX');
      return false; // use return false; to prevent event in case of onsubmit handler, and e.preventDefault for addEventListener event handlers
  }
```

But I would avoid triggering native events like this, since helper funtion way of doing what you need is way simpler to reason about, test and more reliable cross-browser-wise.

Comment: I was thinking about similar solution but I want to trigger the `submit()` and then preventing it (Instead of creating another function)

Comment: @natanelg97 According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit), `onsubmit` will not be fired after you call `submit()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25568709/2119863 will not fire with `.submit()`

Comment: @NathanP. so what can I do? maybe creating an event?

Comment: You should bind event with addEventListener if you really want. Then try to set up a flag to keep track what caused invocation of the event handler. I think it will be dirty, but probably doable.

Comment: ... which will finally be more complicated than creating a function like @dfsq said.

Comment: @NathanP. I agree that creating another function as @dfsq suggested is less complicated than using `addEventListener` (and I appreciate it) but the whole point is doing it without another function - only `onchange` and `onsubmit`

Comment: Actually you can just trigger event properly https://stackoverflow.com/a/17998819/949476 And it will work, but I would avoid triggering native events by all means. But it's up to you, it will work if you really want.

Comment: @dfsq Since it's seems to be complicated, I'll go with the solution that you've offered. Anyway, Thank you very much!